# MStest progress via command line

Tags: command-line, mstest

I am running a big mstest suite from the command line that takes about 15 minutes to complete. Once started the output to the command window is as below...

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading SetupTestRun.testrunconfig...
Loading Test.BusinessLibrary\All.orderedtest...
Starting execution...
```

It remains like this until the test finishes and then dumps all the results to the screen in one big batch. Is there anyway to get a running progress of the tests to the command window so I can see a) how far it has progressed and b) what has passed and failed?

Cheers,

Sam

EDIT: To be clear, we are running an ordered test, not a test list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no command line switches to make this happen. It may be possible using some magic to monitor the files that mstest.exe produces but I haven't had time to explore that angle yet. [You can vote for the feature request here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2344490-mstest-command-line-progress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is possible

Accordingly with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
mstest /testcontainer:YourDLL.dll /detail:errormessage /detail:description /resultsfile:"file.trx"
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it seems to output one line per test as each test happens. So you get an idea of progress overall but not the progress within a test.

I am now looking for a way for it to say test 1/100 test 2/100 etc. would be nice.

Comment: Are you using ordered tests or test lists? We are using ordered tests. We have one top level ordered test with a couple of levels of nesting of ordered tests below that before you get to the actual TestMethods. I guess that's part of my problem. It would be good to know the progress of the TestMethods from the command line as is shown in the Visual Studio UI. Visual Studio shows this progress even when running the ordered tests in our setup.

Comment: No not using anything fancy like that. Just a bunch of tests. Maybe that is why it works for me.